# Need help editing a validation rule

Tags: validation, validation-rule

Validation rule criteria: IF the "Is Owner" field =1, then users shouldn't be able to edit "Commission User ID" nor Territory ID.

```
OR(
(ISCHANGED( Commission_User_Id__c )  || 
ISCHANGED( TerritoryId__c )) and Text(Is_Owner__c, "1"))
```

Comment: Hi user49165 (I swear I'm not a robot, that's just your username), welcome to SFSE! As is, I can't tell what your question is actually about. It seems like you've edited your validation rule just fine. Are you getting an error when you try to save it? Does it save, but it's not working as expected? Basically, I'm asking you to provide more details (things like error messages, or examples that explain that you have data `X` and expect result `Y`, but you're getting result `Z` instead).  Taking a look through the help center, specifically [ask], would be a good idea too.

Comment: What field type is Is_Owner__c?

Answer (score 0):

You have the syntax wrong, and I strongly recommend you don't mix `AND`/`OR` with `&&`/`||` syntax, as it often leads to confusion. First of all, the proper usage:

> `AND(logical1,logical2,...)` and replace `logical1,logical2,...` with the values that you want evaluated.

Same goes for `OR`:

> `OR(logical1, logical2...)` and replace any number of logical references with the expressions you want evaluated.

So as far as your `AND` expression goes, your first logical expression would be to check `Is_Owner__c="1"`, and your second logical expression would be an `OR` clause to check that neither field has changed. Inside your `OR` clause, each expression would be an `ISCHANGED` call.

```
AND(
    Is_Owner__c="1",
    OR(
        ISCHANGED(Field1__c),
        ISCHANGED(Field2__c)
    )
)
```